# silence warnings about unused variables/functions at the point of their conditionally compiled usage

Tags: c++, macros, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

So in [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) (my testing framework) the user can disable all tests by defining the [DOCTEST_CONFIG_DISABLE](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/configuration.md#doctest_config_disable) identifier which makes the following code and macros:

```
TEST_CASE("name") {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;
    CHECK(a == b);
}
```

turn into the following after the preprocessor:

```
template<typename T>
void some_anon_func_123() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;
}
```

that means that the self-registering test case is turned into an uninstantiated template function and the `CHECK()` macro (which functions as an if statement checking the condition) into a no-op - like this:

```
#define CHECK(x) ((void)0) // if disabled
```

However if the user has factored such testing code in a separate function like this:

```
static int g() {
    std::cout << "called!" << std::endl;
    return 42;
}

static void f() {
    int a = 5;
    CHECK(a == g());
}

TEST_CASE("name") {
    f();
}
```

then there will be warnings for unused functions and unused variables. [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) prides itself with producing [**0 warnings even on the most aggressive levels**](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/scripts/common.cmake#L79) so this is unacceptable.

I tried using the `((void) ...)` trick by passing it the macro argument like this:

```
#define CHECK(x) ((void)(x))
```

and that indeed silenced the warnings (atleast for `a` and `g()`) but there is still code being generated for that statement - if I invoke the `f()` function from my `main()` I will see the `called!` string printed in the console. This is undesirable since I want the compilation to be as fast as possible when test cases and asserts are disabled from the build (by using the [DOCTEST_CONFIG_DISABLE](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/configuration.md#doctest_config_disable) identifier). If a user has 100 000 asserts and builds with them disabled he wouldn't want all that unnecessary codegen and compile time overhead for macros that are supposed to be disabled (the `CHECK()` one).

`__attribute__((unused))` has to be used at the point of declaration of a variable - I cannot stick it in the `CHECK()` macro (or can I? I don't know...).

Not sure if `_Pragma()` could help - and even if it could - it is known to have issues with GCC:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55578
- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69543

Is there a solution to my problem - like perhaps passing the expression to some template or whatever...? (C++98 solution needed)

I explained my problem in excruciating detail only because I **often** get accused of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)...

**EDIT:**

A C++11 solution is OK too - some C++11 features have started to conditionally creep into the library anyway...

Comment: What about just using `#define CHECK(x)` instead of `#define CHECK(x) ((void)0)`?

Comment: @Garf365 2 issues with that - first it does not require a semicolon after the macro being used, and secondly - the variable ```a``` and the function ```g()``` will still be unused...

Comment: This is not excruciating detail, this is basic information about what you want to do and what you have tried and why it failed. And speaking of XY problem, why do you not just use `#ifndef DOCTEST_CONFIG_DISABLE`?

Comment: @nwp indeed that can be used, but I cannot ask the user to do so. I want the library to feel as a language feature - fully transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to "lie" to the compiler that you're using a function which you're not actually calling. So how to use a piece of code without executing it?

It seems that the only thing that works on all popular compilers is a C++11-only solution - a lambda which is never called:

```
#define CHECK(x) [&](){ ((void)(x)); }
```

If you absolutely need a c++98 solution, a `sizeof` will also work on many compilers, MSVC being a notable exception:

```
#define CHECK(x) sizeof(x)
```

MSVC will still warn for uncalled functions in the expression `x`.

I guess for maximum coverage you could employ a combination of the two.